# A very silly question about the Erdos-Kac theorem

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, probability-limit-theorems

Let $m$ be a positive integer and let $\omega(m)$ be the number of distinct prime factors of $m$. The Erdos-Kac theorem, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Kac_theorem), is the following: For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\dfrac{1}{n} \# \left\{m \leq n \ : \ \dfrac{\omega(m) - \log\log n}{\sqrt{\log\log n}} \leq x\right\} \right) = \Phi(x) := \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^x e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}} \text{dt}. 
$$
This means that the probability, of a positive integer $m$ having $w$ prime factors given that it was chosen uniformly at random in $[1,n]$, is asymptotically given by the Guassian: 
$$\mathbb{P}(\omega = w) \sim f(w; \mu, \sigma) := \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-\frac{(w - \mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}},$$ 
where $\mu = \log\log n$ and $\sigma = \sqrt \mu$.

Time for a silly question: Since $m > 0$ by assumption, it is clear that if $w \leq 0$, then $\mathbb{P}(\omega = w) = 0$. However $f(w; \mu, \sigma) \neq 0$ for all $w \in \mathbb{R}$, and $0 \not\sim$ to anything different from $0$. What is happening?? That is the set
$$
K_n(w) = \{1 \leq m \leq n \ : \  \omega(m) = w  \}
$$
is empty for all $n$ if $w = 0$. Hence $\frac{1}{n} \# K_n(0) \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ but $f(0; \mu, \sigma)=  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} e^{-\frac{\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}} \neq 0$.

Comment: OK at least we know that the gaussian probability will go to $0$ as $n \to \infty$ for given $\mu$ and $\sigma$. So maybe this question is just arguing on whether $0 \sim $ to anything that goes to $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not to be harsh, but the paragraph that begins "This means that..." is completely false. This simply does not follow from the Erdos-Kac Theorem. Your confusion has nothing to do with this particular result, but seems to be about weak convergence in general.

Take an easier example: let $X$ be standard normal
and consider the sequence $X,X,X,\dots$. This sequence
converges to a standard normal random variable, and yet
the equation 
$$\mathbb{P}(X=x)\sim {1\over\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2}\tag1 $$
is false. Weak convergence makes no
guarantees about $\mathbb{P}(X=x)$ for individual $x$.

As for the silly question, you have to subtract $\log\log n$ from $\omega(m)$ before you get meaningful convergence results. That is, the Erdos-Kac 
 result makes no  claim about your set $K_n(w).$

Comment: Not harsh enough :). Thank you for clarifying my doubt. By this question I was wondering if one could use central limit type results as the above to conclude existence an element $m$ in a set, such as $[1,n]$, satisfying some fixed equation, such as $m = w$ with $w$ a constant. But as you point out, we can not do things such as subtract the mean, etc, here since it is unbounded (it has no saying on fixed conditions such as $m = w$) and the $x$ in the statement of Erdos-Kac is fixed. I hope I'm not misinterpreting things again!

Comment: @user152169 I hope this helps. I suggest that you start to explore "local limit theorems" for results of the type you want.

Comment: @user152169 Rick Durrett's *Probability: theory and examples* is freely available on his website and is a good place to start.

Comment: :) Got it, thanks!